# Teamcity service message jacocoReport

Tags: maven, teamcity, code-coverage, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to get my jacoco report in Teamcity. 
Jacoco runs without any problem with jacoco maven plugin and generates correct report.
I try to get it with the Teamcity service message. I created a separate step immediately after "clean package" step. There I send a message like it is suggested [in Teamcity documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/JaCoCo).

I do it like this

```
echo "##teamcity[jacocoReport dataPath='target/jacoco.exec' includes='zwc.*']"
```

*zwc is my root package*

Also I publish jacoco.exec as an artifact. This way I can verify its correct.

**BUT** Here I have a problem.
In the log I constantly see

```
[11:58:27]  [Step 5/9] Generating JaCoCo coverage...
[11:58:28]  [Generating JaCoCo coverage...] JaCoCo report generating finished
[11:58:28]  [Step 5/9] Publishing JaCoCo coverage...
[11:58:28]  [Publishing JaCoCo coverage...] Coverage was not collected properly. Check your JaCoCo configuration.
```

Unfortunately Teamcity doesn't give any information what went wrong and which configuration is incorrect. In pom or in this service message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Normally TeamCity creates a logfile `/.teamcity/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.log` in the hidden build artifacts. In many cases the reason is e.g. a wrong filtering or wrong pattern, which can be recognized by the statement:

> total 0 classfiles processed, 0 analyzed

You may need to add a classpath search pattern like it is described in [TeamCity Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/jacoco.html#JaCoCo-ImportingJaCoCocoveragedatatoTeamCity). For example: `+:target/main/java/**`

Or you can try to check your includes in general (eg. if it really matches what you want to include or if there is a spelling mistake or something like that).

Comment: That's correct, see my answer on this old post https://stackoverflow.com/a/56953121/2914666